# There seems to be 2 different variables with the same name in my class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I declared a private int tree_count in a class SpawnManager.
void Start() and void Update() uses the variable as expected, but another method, public void Tree_destroyed seems to be using a different tree_count.

Here is my code.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int tree_count;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tree_count = 500;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time < 3.05)
        {
            print(tree_count);
        }

    }
    
    public void Tree_destroyed()
    {
        tree_count--;
        print(tree_count);
    }
}
```

void Update() prints 500 for the tree_count, but public void Tree_destroyed() prints 0, and goes to -1, -2,... for every method call.

public void Tree_destroyed() is called by an object with this script:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TreeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnManager;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject, 3);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        spawnManager.GetComponent<SpawnManager>().Tree_destroyed();
    }
}
```

Any idea why it behaves like that? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: For the order of things that happen: first, private int tree_count is initialized, void Start() is called which sets tree_count to 500, void Update() is called every frame, which shows tree_count as 500, void Tree_destroyed is called after 3 seconds, which shows a different tree_count, void Update() is called in the next frame, showing tree_count as still 500.

EDIT 2: There are only 3 objects in the scene, the camera (no scripts attached), object with SpawnManager, and another object that calls Tree_destroyed when destroyed. I'm sure there are no duplicate objects or scripts.

Comment: you have two different instances of `SpawnManager`, and for the second you never call the `Start` method. That's my guess.

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually call 'Tree_destroyed()' ?

Comment: Does everything happen in one and the same thread?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by the same thread. If you're referring to how my computer processor processes these scripts, I have no idea.

Comment: Can you try moving `Destroy(gameObject, 3)` from Start() to Update() ? In case the object is destroyed before the SpawnManager is 'started' this may be the problem.

Comment: I tried it just now, and it doesn't change the results. void Start() is typically used for initialization, hence it is always called first. void Update() is for processing normal gameplay, and is called for every frame once. Moving Destroy() should only delay Tree_destroyed() by about 1 frame. I'm sure that Tree_destroyed() is being called because of the odd 0 output after 3 seconds of running the game (-1,-2,-3,.. if I add more trees in the scene).

Comment: My idea was that you can never be sure which Start() is going to be called first - the SpawnManager's or TreeBehaviour's. In your code you  assume that SpawnManager's Start() is called first.

Comment: It shouldn't matter in this case, since void onDestroy() is the one that calls Tree_destroyed() which only happens after 3 seconds. My output basically becomes 500, 500, 500, ..., 500, 500, 0, -1, -2,..., -5, -6, -7, 500, 500, 500 (the number of outputs near 0 is based on the number of trees I instantiated, in this example is 8).

Comment: I tried the setup you described (camera object without any scripts, one empty object with the SpawnManager script, and one empty object with the TreeBehavoir script) and I got 500, 500, ..., 500,  500, 499, 499, 499, 499.

Comment: @eClySe you are right. It should be ok like this. I just tried the whole example and it works as expected.

Comment: I tried setting up a new scene with just the 3 objects only and got the intended result. Upon closer inspection, in my original scene, the gameObject linked in TreeBehaviour is a prefab of my spawnManager object, and is not linked to the object with spawnManager in my scene. Thank you for the help, and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that because this is a class object that there are two instances of objects with the same private variable. Without seeing the rest of your project this is the most likely answer.

Comment: The project is pretty new, with only 3 objects in the scene (camera, object with SpawnManager, and object that calls Tree_destroyed() when destroyed), so I'm sure that there are no duplicates.